# Store string and foreign key in one column

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm building a website with a large number of categories, each with its own specific form fields. Because there are so many categories, I wanted to store those form fields in a database.

1. The categories are stored in a `category` table:

   ```
   id | name
   -------------
   1  | Car info
   ```
2. The fields for that category are stored in a `category_field` table:

   ```
   id | fk_id_category | type  | label
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   1  | 1              | text  | Your name
   2  | 1              | radio | What type of car do your drive?
   ```
3. If a `category_field` has some predefined options from which the user can choose then these are stored in a `category_field_option` table:

   ```
   id | fk_id_category_field | label
   -----------------------------------------
   1  | 2                    | 'Convertible'
   2  | 2                    | 'Truck'
   3  | 2                    | 'Minivan'
   ```

Now, when a user fills out a form we want to save a reference to this in a `form_entry` table:

```
    id | fk_id_user | fk_id_category
    --------------------------------
    1  | 1          | 1
```

The details of that form entry are saved in a `form_entry_details` table. However:

- If the `category_field.type` is `text` we should just save the answer as string

  ```
  id | fk_id_form_entry | fk_id_category_field | [answer]
  -------------------------------------------------------
  1  | 1                | 1                    | John Doe
  ```
- If the `category_field.type` is `radio`, I want to save a foreign key to the `category_field_option`

  ```
  id | fk_id_form_entry | fk_id_category_field | [fk_id_category_field_option]
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2  | 1                | 2                    | 2
  ```

How can I solve this? I know I could just store the `fk_id_category_field_option` as a string, but I need it to actually reference to the `category_field_option` table since I'm using an ORM (Doctrine 1.2.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because the whole idea of foreign keys is to prevent this sort of situation. You either store it as one field without an enforce foreign key or you create two columns, one for the foreign key id (perhaps a default value that relates to 'user defined') and another that takes the user defined info and, probably, defaults to null.

Comment: Thanks! One thing though, what do you mean with _perhaps a default value that relates to 'user defined'_? Why can't the foreign key id be NULL?

Comment: As far as I know NULL would be a valid value. So that should work as well.